# How to displaying a PDF Document in outside folder in the Browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, pdf, razor

Currently i'm working with document management system project technology is ASP.Net MVC 3 . i want to display pdf document that is located in folder in my hard drive(C:,D: E: ect). i tried to `<embed>` tag. but it didn't work. it worked for files inside my project. Also i don't need to download that pdf and read. i need to dispaly it somewhere in my view.

i saw this code segment. but i don't know how to use this..

```
public FileResult GetFile(string fileName)
{
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + fileName + ";");
    string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "App_Data/";            
    return File(path + fileName, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf, fileName);
}
```

Can someone help me to solve this problem.
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You may ise the [`File`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492593%28v=vs.98%29) method of Controller class. This will return the PDF to browser.

```
public ActionResult GetFile(string fileName)
{
  string fullPathToFile=SomeMethodToGetFullPathFromFileName(fileName);
  return File(fullPathToFile,"application/pdf","someFriendlyName.pdf")
}
```

Assuming `SomeMethodToGetFullPathFromFileName` is a method which returns the full path to the PDF file

You may use `Server.MapPath` method to get the full (physical) path to the file.

If you want to view this in the browser, you can access it like

```
yoursitename/someControllername/getfile?fileName=somepdffilenamehere
```

Comment: File was downloaded. i need to display that pdf some where in my "View".

Answer (score 0):

The code you have shown represents a controller action that serves files from the `App_Code` folder. Serving files from arbitrary locations on the hard drive would be a huge security vulnerability. So I would recommend you sticking with this approach. But there are still flaws in this code. A malicious user could still display arbitrary files on your hard drive by using a specially crafted url. This could be fixed with the following action:

```
public ActionResult GetFile(string file)
{
    var appData = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
    var path = Path.Combine(appData, file);
    path = Path.GetFullPath(path);
    if (!path.StartsWith(appData))
    {
        // Ensure that we are serving file only inside the App_Data folder
        // and block requests outside like "../web.config"
        throw new HttpException(403, "Forbidden");
    }

    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(path))
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    return File(path, MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);
}
```

and now you could use the `embed` tag to link to this controller action:

```
<object data="@Url.Action("GetFile", "SomeController", new { file = "test.pdf" })" type="application/pdf" width="300" height="200">
  alt : @Html.ActionLink("test.pdf", "SomeController", "Home", new { file = "test.pdf" })
</object>
```

or an `iframe` if you prefer:

```
<iframe src="@Url.Action("GetFile", "SomeController", new { file = "foo.pdf" })" style="width:718px; height:700px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```