# asp.net mvc 4 download pdf not working

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, pdf

I want to try out to download pdf in the browser.

I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12356499/how-to-displaying-a-pdf-document-in-outside-folder-in-the-browser), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27477684/file-download-using-asp-net-mvc),

Now in my code, I followed the links and here's what I got.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult DownloadPdf(){
  var path = Server.MapPath("~/Doc/Pdf/sample.pdf");
  return File(path , "application/pdf", "sample.pdf");
}
```

View

```
<a href="#" id="download-pdf">Download PDF</a>
```

Javascript

```
$("#download-pdf").click(function() {
  $.post("/Home/DownloadPdf");
  return false;
});
```

Folder Structure:

```
Solution
-- Project
---- ....
---- Doc
------ Pdf
-------- sample.pdf
```

When I try to examine the developer's tool in chrome.

I got a 200 status and in the preview tab, I got some characters. I think it is the content of the pdf.

Now my problem is, the pdf won't show up in the browser as downloaded file.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why not just have `@Html.ActionLink("Download PDF", "DownloadPdf", new{controller="Home"}, new{target="_blank"})` instead of all of the jQuery stuff going on?  Also, you are issuing a POST for what looks to be a GET request.

Comment: Ok let me try that out. How about in my controller? Do you see anything odd?

Comment: Looks fine to me - should work as is with a normal `<a>` link.

Comment: try this <a href="/Home/DownloadPdf" id="download-pdf">Download PDF</a>

Comment: you have to just pass href= " pdf reference path" in anchor tag

Comment: It's working now. Thank you so much. But what do you think is the reason why it's not working doing the jquery stuff?

Comment: you were not referencing the exact path through jquery

Comment: :) thanks dear if it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

< a href="/Home/DownloadPdf" id="download-pdf">Download PDF< /a>